# How do I print on a USB printer that is connected and working on a Ubuntu Server?

Tags: networking, server, printing

I have installed a USB Printer (Canon MF4400) on my Ubuntu Server and it works perfectly, if I print directly from the server. (I have downloaded the correct drivers from canon).
On the Ubuntu client machine I have installed that printer as a network printer with the cups-web-application (localhost:631). I also downloaded and installed the correct canon driver and selected that driver on the client machine.
If I want to print from the client machine, nothing happens. 
I installed a clone-printer (test) on the server according to the guide on [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems) and printed from the client machine to that clone. On the server I received that file that should go to the printer and was able to print it correctly with the command `lp -d <printer> -oraw <file>` from the server.
Now I suspect, that because I have installed the printer drivers on the client-machine as well as on the server-machine, the printer gets confused and does nothing.
So my question is:
Where do I have to install the printer driver, on the client or on the server or on both machines?
If only on one machine, how do I have to configure the printer on the other machine without having to select a printer-driver?

Comment: two questions to clear up the situation, 1) is the server set to share the printer? 2) does the client discover the printer?

Comment: both aswers are yes. The client discovers the printer and asks to install a printer driver. The installation on the client side works fine but the printer doesn't print, not even a test page. On the client side I installed the same driver like on the server (Canon MF4400 Series UFRII LT)

Comment: After 3 Month of unsucessfully searching the web I just tried to install the printer on the server as a raw printer without driver  - and it worked!    The steps are as follows:   lpadmin -p CANON_MF4400 -E -v usb://Canon/MF4400%20Series?serial=111685202894&interface=1
   Do **not** use the cups-web interface because it will force you to select a printer.  On the client machine install the printer normally from the settings->printers menue.